# Looking for the best ec2 setup for 3 sites totaling in 1.5 mil in traffic monthly

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, performance, load-balancing, amazon-web-services

I am looking to consolidate our current aws setup of 2 Large ubuntu ec2 servers and 2 large RDS server for our 3 websites that have a total of about 1.5 million hits a month and increasing every month with the majority of traffic (1 mil) to one forum site in the group and the rest of traffic to an ecommerce site and a small wordpress site.

So here is my question/thought?

Would it be better for us to combine the two ec2 large servers to just one and same with the 2 RDS servers so we run all three sites off one large ec2 and one RDS.
-or-
Should we setup maybe 2-3 smaller ec2 servers load balenced and a single RDS. 
-or- 
Something completely different setup?

One concern is that if one site crashes it takes with it the others. It happened in the past but I am pretty sure its because of the forum software and not the server setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get at least 3 small or medium instances and put them in different zones. I'll install all the websites/forum software on all three of them and ensure that they are identical. Then I would get a Elastic load balancer and put it in front of these three instances. Now all the three websites are load balanced and highly available. Even if one of the instance blow up, your websites will survive.

One rds with Multi-AZ enabled would be enough.

PS: I don't recommend using 2 instances because with your load, if one instance fails, other one may not be able to handle all the requests and will probably fail too.